# A word for people who are not guests

Tags: word-choice

In our application users can register permanently or do a guest check-out. The users that are using guest checkout are *guests*.

Is there a word for people who are not guests?

Comment: _nonguest_ is a word also. (maybe not suitable for your context)

Comment: @Josh61 You should post that as an answer.

Comment: *Registered user* is what I seem to see most often.

Comment: If you're going for a "club" analogy, there are _members_ and _guests_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to [member:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Italian%2CItalic&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CItalian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CItalic%3B%2Cc0):

> - One that belongs to a group or an organization: a club member; a bank that is a member of the FDIC.

Source:w ww.thefreedictionary.com